# how to persist serialized array to database?

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

I'm using Symfony2 and FOSUserBundle.

I serialized an array and saved it into an array type. How do I persist the associative array into the database?

I get errors...: `EntityManager#persist() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, array given.`

or `EntityManager#persist() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, string given.`

...depending on which array I persist.

```
        $this->userCartArrayValues = serialize($cartArray);
        $em->persist($this->userCartArrayValues);
        // $em->persist($cartArray);
        $em->flush();
        var_dump($this->userCartArrayValues);
```

any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Two accounts and two identical questions will probably not get you much in the line of answers.  I'd suggest making at 5 more accounts and posting the same question at least a dozen times.  That should give you more visibility.  And be sure to ignore any responses you do get.  Proper etiquette is important.

Answer (score 0):

you can cast an array to an object like so...

```
$object = json_decode(json_encode($array), FALSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Persist method only take entity object. You can't send serialized data. I think best solution is get data directly of entity object instead of array. Or maybe you can use JMSSerilizerBundle as well.

```
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->setBar($cartArray['bar']);

$em->persist($foo);
$em->flush();
```

Or this is little bit messy but you can create new Entity Object and set values then you can persist.